# PCRE not supporting patterns more than 1024 length in C

Tags: c, pcre

We are using PCRE pattern in our C code to do the matching. We are keep on adding patterns and now it crossed 1024 characters. Now the PCRE is not loading for this key at all.

Is there any limitation on PCRE like above?

What all are the alternatives?

Appreciate your support.

Thanks,
Mathew Liju

Comment: All i found is `12.9 Limitations

There are some size limitations in PCRE but it is hoped that they will never in practice be relevant. The maximum length of a compiled pattern is 65539 (sic) bytes. All values in repeating quantifiers must be less than 65536. The maximum number of capturing subpatterns is 99. The maximum number of all parenthesized subpatterns, including capturing subpatterns, assertions, and other types of subpattern, is 200.` from http://users-cs.au.dk/beta/Manuals/latest/basiclib/pcre.html

Comment: And `       The maximum length of a compiled pattern is 65539 (sic) bytes  if  PCRE
       is compiled with the default internal linkage size of 2. If you want to
       process regular expressions that are truly enormous,  you  can  compile
       PCRE  with  an  internal linkage size of 3 or 4 (see the README file in
       the source distribution and the pcrebuild documentation  for  details).
       In  these  cases the limit is substantially larger.  However, the speed
       of execution is slower.` from http://man.he.net/man3/pcre

Comment: What do you need patterns longer than 1024 chars for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, we have split the regex into smaller chunks and resolved.

Appreciate for the comments.